# Tomcat started but cannot be accessed through http in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, tomcat8

I am starting tomcat 8.5.9 in Ubuntu 16.04 like this

[image]

I checked the process

[image]

However, I cannot access it through browser

http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxx:8080/test

The result is this

[image]